# How to read millions of rows(575.7 MB) from AWS S3 gzipped file to Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The file is copied into S3 from **Snowflake** using COPY INTO in airflow. It is creating a **gzip** file to S3(but with .csv extension) and I would like to read it into DataFrame.
I've tried numerous ways(With gzip.GzipFile(), Dask, pd.read_csv(compression='gzip', loading in chunks) but it takes too long and Airflow will exit with an error: `Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGKILL` (Most of those solutions won't even end loading in Jupyter).

What would be the most effective way to do this?

P.S I don't really need the file from Snowflake to S3 but just to a Dataframe(from table) and I've also tried getting chunks of data from Snowflake using `Snowflakehook.get_pandas_df(query='SELECT * FROM table limit {} offset {})` append those sub_df's to a list and then **pd.concat** them together but this will also exit with SIGKILL after getting only 1 million rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this dataset small enough that you can reasonably hold the whole thing in memory? 1) If you load the first 100,000 rows into memory, and run `df.memory_usage`, how big is that? 2) How many rows are there?

Comment: 75 columns, every column seems to be 800 000 bytes. The dataset itself is 15million

Comment: Some back-of-the envelope math suggests that will be around 9GB of memory usage, and double that when you do the concatenation step. Can your airflow instances hold that much data?

Comment: Dev env: 
5 concurrent tasks (by default)
1 vCPUs
2 GB RAM
Prod env: 
10 concurrent tasks (by default)
2 vCPUs
4 GB RAM
So I guess not :D

Comment: Have you looked into Snowflake Python support for Snowpark?  This would allow you to do pandas logic on a dataframe directly in Snowflake...no need to unload it to a different machine.  It's in preview, but perhaps you can get it enabled on request.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll look into it.

Comment: But if I won't get SnowPark enabled right now, do you know if there's any other efficient way to do this?